# Unification algorithm - need clarification

Tags: logic, unification

I have these two terms:

**{P(a,x,x),P(a,b,c)}**

I'm supposed to find if the terms and unifiable using the unification algorithm.

I'd do the following substitutions:

***b/x***, resulting in : **{P(a,b,b),P(a,b,c)}**

***c/b***, resulting in : **{P(a,c,c),P(a,c,c)}**

And thus the two terms are unifiable.
However, the solution in my book says that the terms aren't unifiable.
My intuition tells me that **P(a,b,c)** is not the same as **P(a,c,c)** and so I can't do the ***c/b*** substitution. However, I'd like some further more general clarification, which my book lacks.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which are constants and which are variables? I believe a,b,c would be constants and x would be the variable, but this is usually defined either implicitly through notation standards or explicitly in the problem. You can't substitute constants with constants, as that would change the very meanings of the terms.

Comment: I typically find it to be the case that books don't lack much, but students reading the books think they do. In the present case, I think you should consult your book to see if it speaks about the fact that some symbols are variables (or meta-variables, or uknowns, or unification variables) and others are constants (or terms).

Comment: Thank you, the book didn't specify which were constants and which were variables, perhaps it relied on notation standards.